# Execute complex SQL queries

Tags: database

I need to execute these SQL instructions.

```
CREATE TABLE superstatistics_counter LIKE node_counter;
INSERT superstatistics_counter SELECT * FROM node_counter;
```

When I run the query, it runs. I expect the node_counter table to get a big table with about 100000 rows. 
This is what I have tried:

1. With `hook_schema()` I have created the superstatistics_counter table
2. With this code I tried to copy data from the node_counter table

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM `node_counter`";
   $data = db_query($sql)->fetchAll();
   foreach ($data as $dataObject) {
     $dataArray = array($dataObject->nid, $dataObject->totalcount, $dataObject->daycount, $dataObject->timestamp);
     $query = \Drupal::database()->insert('superstatistics_counter');
     $query->fields([
       'nid',
       'totalcount',
       'daycount',
       'timestamp'
     ]);
     $query->values($dataArray);
     $query->execute();
   }
   ```

It caused the following error:

> Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded

So it is very slow.

When I executed it in phpMyAdmin, it output the following.

> MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.1401 seconds.)
>   `CREATE TABLE superstatistics_counter LIKE node_counter`

> 100000 rows inserted. (Query took 0.9567 seconds.)
>       INSERT superstatistics_counter SELECT * FROM node_counter

Is there a way to just execute this query in Drupal, without using `db_query()` and `\Drupal::database()->insert()`? Can it be done on MySQL side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`db_query`](https://api.drupal.org/db_query) function  isn't just for select queries, it will execute anything.

Just use that instead of the loop, the performance will be miles better:

```
db_query('INSERT INTO superstatistics_counter SELECT * FROM node_counter');
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 
In official documentation is this: `Use this function for SELECT queries if it is just a simple query string. If the caller or other modules need to change the query, use db_select() instead.
Do not use this function for INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE queries. Those should be handled via db_insert(), db_update() and db_delete() respectively.`

So it confused me and I didnt try to use db_query()....

Comment: Yeah that's a bit of a shame. The docs mean well but the information is wrong